# SAPI 5.4 grammars compatible with SAPI 5.1?

Tags: c#, sapi

I wrote an application in C# for win 7 which used .NET 4.0 and SAPI 5.4 by using a SharedRecognizer in System.Speech. Everything works in that environment, but not on Windows XP.

On Win XP (with SAPI 5.1 installed) it doesn't seem to like the grammar xml files I'm using.

The program crashes trying to read a grammar file with the following error:

```
This semantic interpretation type 'tag-format' is not supported with this 
version of the speech platform.
```

After some searching I found someone else who had a very similar problem on [this forum](http://www.geekpedia.com/Thread18646_SAPI-53-On-XP.html) but it didn't seem the problem was ever solved.

Anyone have any ideas? Do I need to have two version of the Grammar files, one for XP and one for Win Vista/7? If so does anyone know of a side by side explanation of what's different so I can come up with a simple way to translate from one to the other? And if I do have the grammar files in different formats could I actually load the older version in the SharedRecognizer which I'm assuming is a SAPI 5.3-4 class? Or would I have to use COM calls to the SAPI 5.1 dll instead of the System.Speech namespace?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I figured this out. The issue is that SAPI 5.3 and above support SRGS (Speech Recognition Grammar Specification) which I used. However, earlier version of SAPI do not support this format and thus the errors I was getting.

I think the work around would be to use text grammars instead, and I'm now trying to figure out how to do that. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588739/how-do-i-load-a-text-grammar-in-a-sapi-5-4-c-program) for more information!